# Python script does not display anyoutput in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using the below code in pycharm:-

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import pandas


start_date=date(2021, 5,1)
end_date=date.today()

df = get_history(symbol='SBIN' ,start=start_date, end=end_date )
print(df)
```

However it does not display anything in pycharm.

Comment: Sorry for my question but do you run your code?

Comment: to add to @Corralien do you run this code? you could be running some other without noticing and the other one doesn't output anything (had this happen to me like the day before yesterday) also in case you are running it all correctly try printing out anything else like `print('test')` if it shows up it would indicate an issue with `get_history`

Comment: maybe `get_history` returns only white-spaces. (space / newline / indentation)

Comment: Yes I ran the code and its still fetching it seems like but is there any way to get NSE data quickly  by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm that copying and pasting your code returns data in the console as you can see below. I suspect you are running another script/tab when you click run in PyCharm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem was the companies VPN connection blocking the NSEPY APi.
Disabling the VPN and runing the code gave the output.